# Which stats (if any) affect accuracy?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

The pre-game manual in my /docs install folder for the game says that Perception affects accuracy. However, the in-game tooltip for Perception doesn't say this, and the Accuracy tooltip also makes no mention of it.

Is this a case of the manual being out of date, or the tooltip not reflecting reality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip is correct and the manual is out of date. Perception was changed to no longer affect accuracy after the manual was prepared.

The changes can be found in the [manual errata](http://eternity.obsidian.net/manual/errata).

> **Attributes**
>
> Perception now affects Interrupt, Deflection, and Reflex.
>
> Intellect now affects the Will defense and Durations and Areas of Effect for all abilities and talents.
>
> Resolve now affects Concentration, Deflection, and Will.

There are no longer any stats which affect accuracy, but there are some talents and racial passives, such as the [wood elf's Distant Advantage passive](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Distant_Advantage) which adds +5 accuracy against enemies over 4m away.

There are a series of "weapon focus" talents available on level-up (in the offensive tab) that add accuracy with certain types of weapons. There are also some class-specific talents available which enhance accuracy with certain weapons or with specific class skills.

The full list of available talents can be found [on the official wikl](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Talent#Known_Talents)

Comment: The wiki is bad right now. Really, really, really, really bad.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz those specific pages seem to match in game screens, is that more of an overall assessment of the wiki or a criticism against some sections?

Comment: General comment. Though it should be noted that as of 8 hours ago, the weapon talents on the list were in fact wrong. It'll be good eventually, but I'd not rely on it right now.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I'll grab some screenshots next time I level up, those should be more correct

Comment: Oh, they're correct now. My point is just that the wiki is kind of in shambles. Click through on, say... Weapon Focus:Ruffian to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

The manual is out of date. Obsidian [maintains a comprehensive Errata page for it.](http://eternity.obsidian.net/game/manual-errata) Perception is an exclusively defensive stat.

**Accuracy** is exclusively a function of class level, buffs, talents, etc. You cannot increase it with any statistic.